# Selenium IDE - verify content of Cookie

Tags: selenium

Does anyone know how I would go about verifying that a cookie value contains a text substring in Selenium IDE?

e.g. if I had a cookie called 'MyCookie' which had as its contents 'This is my value', and I wanted to assert that the cookie contained the substring 'value', is this possible using the IDE?

**Update**

Solution is as follows

```
storeCookieByName | MyCookie | variable1

storeEval | storedVars['variable1'].indexOf('value') > 0 ? true: false|result;

verifyExpression | $(result) | true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IDE use the storeCookieByName function providing the cookie name and the variable name you want the value to store the cookie into.

Comment: OK, that stored the cookie value in the variable...how do I then check that the variable contains a substring?

Comment: you can use storeEval and look for the substring in JS

Answer (score 4):

In selenium ide `storeCookieByName`(name, variableName) function return the value of cookies, in this function you provide only cookies name in target column and write any variable in value column

```
       Command       |    Target   |  value
   storeCookieByName | mf_user     | test
      echo           | ${test}
```

name - the name of the cookie.

storeCookieByName function Returns: the value of the cookie